# index button to open a contact form in for loop in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a card view in my site

How do I address my button which should open a pop up contact form

````
{% for dat in placeddata %}
  <div class="col-sm">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="{{dat.student.profileimg}}" width="250px" height="250px" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{dat.student.user.get_full_name}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Has been placed in {{dat.company.Comp_name}} Company.</p>
    <img width="50px" class="img-fluid" src="{{dat.company.profileimg}}">

    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}```
````

Comment: You just have to set the `href` of the button element : `<a href="{% url 'link_to_your_popup_form' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</a>`

Comment: i want to address the receiver too